# Fix width of one column in a row in Semantic ui

Tags: semantic-ui

How can I have two column in a row in Semantic UI that one of column have a fix width and doesn't change with resizing of browser?

I tried this, but something went wrong:

```html
<div class="ui grid container">
  <div class="ui two column divided grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ui four wide  column" style="width= 250px;">
      </div>
      <div class="ui twelve wide  column">
        <div class="ui link cards">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="./lib/img/elliot.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">Matt Giampietro</div>
              <div class="meta">
                <a>Friends</a>
              </div>
              <div class="description">
                Matthew is an interior designer living in New York.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="extra content">
              <span class="right floated">
              Joined in 2013
              </span>
              <span>
              <i class="user icon"></i>
              75 Friends
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no SUI specific way (yet), so you'll have to write custom CSS

You are using too many SUI classes in your code.

This is not required: `<div class="ui grid container">` when you are defining another grid inside it.

The `two column` class in `<div class="ui two column divided grid">` is redundant as well.

So solve your problem, you can change the first column classes and then use CSS to fix its width.
See JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/5289q8fr/1/

```html
<div class="left column">
  Some Text
</div>
<div class="twelve wide  column">
<div class="ui link cards">
```

And corresponding CSS property:

```css
#grid .left.column {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Don't use the classes such as `two wide` in a column you want to keep fixed as they have some associated width properties that might override the behavior of `.left.column`

For Responsiveness, you'll have to manage the padding/margins a bit as well near the breakpoint or use media queries to update the class of the `twelve wide column`.

Answer (score 19):

I solved this by using flexbox which ui grid uses.

```html
<div class="ui two grid">
  <div class="column" style="flex: 1;"></div>
  <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: absolutely brilliant solution. it works for me too.

Comment: Works on desktop, but columns overlap on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Semantic UI framework doesn't provide fixed-width column support. In certain ways it can be solved by next way:

```
<style>
    .fixed-one-column {
         visibility: hidden;
     }
</style>
<div class="ui on wide column fixed-one-column">
    content#1
</div>
<div class="ui five wide column fixed-one-column">
    content#2
</div>
<div class="ui five wide column fixed-one-column">
    content#3
</div>
<script>
var max = -1;
$('.fixed-one-column').each(function() {
 if(parseFloat($(this).css('width').replace('px','')) > max) {   
    max =  parseFloat($(this).css('width').replace('px',''));
 }       
});
$('.fixed-one-column').css({'width':max+'px', 'visibility: initial'});
<script>
```